# Java ArrayList is not adding up correctly

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having trouble with the logic I think. My results are not adding up correctly. Can someone please help? The problem is in the `arrayList.size`, `nums.length` or something. I entered 50 40 60 as my integers.

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.print("Enter integers please ");
        System.out.println("(EOF or non-integer to terminate): ");

        while (input.hasNextInt()) {
            list.add(input.nextInt());
        }

        Integer[] nums = list.toArray(new Integer[0]);
        System.out.printf("%s", "You entered: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {         
            System.out.printf("%d%s", nums[i], ", ");
        }

        Collections.sort(list);
        int b = Collections.max(list);
        int c = Collections.min(list);
        int arraySize = nums.length-1;
        double sum = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            sum += list.get(i);
        }
        System.out.println(" \nLast Number is : " + list.get(arraySize)
                + "\nLargest Number is: " + b 
                + "\nSmallest number is :" + c 
                + "\n" + "You entered " + (arraySize+1) + " numbers"
                + "\nTotal numbers added up is: " + sum 
                + "\nAverage number is: " + (sum / (nums.length)));
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What are you expecting and what is it doing instead?

Comment: I am expecting a proper element count and I want to be able to tell the user the last number they entered.

Comment: Run your code step-by-step under debugger and examine all the values as you go.

Comment: THAT is not the issue. It works just not logically. For example, I am getting the wrong "last number" displayed unless I change "arraySize" to "arraySize-1". Why is that. I also figured out that my variable "average" must be placed AFTER the for loop. Any ideas?

Comment: This is what I get from running your code: `Enter integers please (EOF or non-integer to terminate): 
10
20
30
s
You entered: 10, 20, 30,  
Last Number is : 30
Largest Number is: 30
Smallest number is :10
You entered 3 numbers
Total numbers added up is: 60.0
Average number is: 20.0
`

Comment: try entering 30 10 20 and test that. What I need is an explanation is why must I add "-1" to array size in order for it to sysout the "last number entered" correctly. Thank you for the rep up vote.

Comment: @twitter your list is already get sorted so it will always return last element after sorting which is not last as expected. refer anwer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sorting list so it will return last value from sorted list. `Collections.sort(list)` is sorting asc so you get max number from the list. First approach,

1) Either you have to manage origanal list before sorting like

```
 ArrayList<Integer> ori = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
 Collections.sort(list);
```

And get the value from ori.

```
 System.out.println(" \nLast Number is : " + ori.get(list.size()-1)
```

2) Second approach,  Create variable which will store temp last entered value. you can use it.
Might it helps!!

So your example like:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            System.out.print("Enter integers please ");
            System.out.println("(EOF or non-integer to terminate): ");

            while (input.hasNextInt()) {
                list.add(input.nextInt());
            }

            Integer[] nums = list.toArray(new Integer[0]);
            System.out.printf("%s", "You entered: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {         
                System.out.printf("%d%s", nums[i], ", ");
            }
            ArrayList<Integer> ori = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
            Collections.sort(list);
            int b = Collections.max(list);
            int c = Collections.min(list);
            int arraySize = nums.length-1;
            double sum = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            {
                sum += list.get(i);
            }
            System.out.println(" \nLast Number is : " + ori.get(list.size()-1)
                    + "\nLargest Number is: " + b 
                    + "\nSmallest number is :" + c 
                    + "\n" + "You entered " + (arraySize+1) + " numbers"
                    + "\nTotal numbers added up is: " + sum 
                    + "\nAverage number is: " + (sum / (nums.length)));
            input.close();

    }
```

Comment: I commented out the sorting. I then removed the "-1" and it works out. I will now do research on why this is working- though any explanations would help.

Comment: `Collections.sort(list)` is perform sorting on list default `asc`. If u comment it, it will be on same state which u have fill. from where u remove `-1`?  u can debug code for the best knowhow.